# Cannot find symbol : constructor

Tags: java

When I compile I am getting the error: 
cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Team()

```
public class Team {
    public String name;
    public String location;
    public double offense;
    public double defense;

    public Team(String name, String location) {

    }     

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter name and location for home team");
        Scanner tn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Team team = new Team();
        team.name = tn.nextLine(); 

        Scanner tl = new Scanner(System.in);
        team.location = tl.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to fix?
many thanks
Miles

Comment: Read the error message? It's quite clear; you're trying to use a constructor that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

If you explicitly create any constructor in class, compiler does not provide default constructor. You need to create `no-args` constructor explicitly.

> If a class does not explicitly declare any, the Java compiler
>   automatically provides a no-argument constructor, called the default
>   constructor. This default constructor calls the class parent's
>   no-argument constructor, or the Object constructor if the class has no
>   other parent. If the parent has no constructor (Object does have one),
>   the compiler will reject the program.

[Read more on Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

*Updated Code* -

```
public class Team {
    public String name;
    ...
    public Team(){...}
    public Team(String name, String location) {...}   
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

provide default constructor to resolve error

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a non-parameter constructor to your class as well. As you are trying to call the non-paremeter constructor here:

```
    Team team = new Team();
```

Just add this to your class also:

```
public Team() {

}
```

Generally when there is no constructor defined in a class then compiler adds a default non-parameter constructor to it. But if any non-default constructor is added then compiler will not add the default non-param constructor. That need to be added manually as mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

In your Team class, there is no default constructor, but you created object using of it.
Try,

```
public class Team {
    public String name;
    public String location;
    public double offense;
    public double defense;

    public Team(){}

    public Team(String name, String location) {

    }     

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter name and location for home team");
        Scanner tn = new Scanner(System.in);
        Team team = new Team();
        team.name = tn.nextLine(); 

        Scanner tl = new Scanner(System.in);
        team.location = tl.nextLine();
    }
}
```

If you have other constructors you must define a no-arg constructor by yourself as Java only provides a default no-argument constructor if no other constructors are defined.

Answer (score 1):

No argument constructor nor valid here. Since you are override it by following

```
public Team(String name, String location) {

}
```

So you can't do `Team team = new Team();` .

instead of this try

```
      Team team = new Team("Name","Location");
```

since your constructor only accept two `String` arguments.  Or you can add no argument constructor to your `Team` class.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor you defined is public Team(String name, String location) which takes two arguments.

However, the constructor you called is Team() which takes no arguments, which means it is a different constructor from Team(String name, String location), as they have different arguments list.

You should define a Team() too if you want to create an empty Team object